# Mule code to convert elements in array to individual element qoutes

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I want to create a dynamic insert query in mulesoft as part of the system API that is can be used to interact with DB for multiple tables as per the calling processing API.

I want to below outout

```
"Ronaldo","GOAT"
```

But I'm getting below output

```
"Ronaldo, GOAT"
```

Can someone please help me, I'm trying to create a dynamic insert but values needs to be in double quotes.

Below is my current logic,

PAYLOAD

```
{
    "table": "std",
    "Payload": {
        "studentName" : "Ronaldo" ,
        "course" : "GOAT"
    }
}
```

CODE

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var table = "insert into " ++ payload.table

var value  = valuesOf(payload.Payload) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> item  ++"," ++ accumulator)

var key = keysOf(payload.Payload) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> item ++ "," ++ accumulator)

---

table ++ key ++ "(VALUES  " ++ value ++");"
```

OUTPUT

"Ronadlo","GOAT"

Comment: Your output is incomplete. You should show the entire output, not just the part you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script can be simpler and there are some possible improvements:

- Use the [namesOf() function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dw-core-functions-namesof) instead of `keysOf()`. The former returns keys as an Array of Strings while the later returns an Array of Keys, a different type that has to be converted and could case issues with comparisons.
- Use `map()` to transform the values to add double quotes before and after each String in the array. Example: if `a` is an array the `a map ("\""++$++"\"")` will concatenate a double quote before and after each string of `a`.
- We can encapsulate the entire transformation in a function to avoid repeating it for both variables.
- Once you get an array of Strings just use the [joinBy() function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dw-core-functions-joinby) to join the Strings with a separator (a comma in this case).
- The output format should be Java if you want to use the output for an SQL query. Using JSON will require extra conversions and be less performant. Java is the native format of Mule.
- Assuming that the output is an SQL insert the syntax is wrong. I used the standard syntax for it.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
fun listOfString(a)=a map ("\""++$++"\"") joinBy ","
var values = listOfString(valuesOf(payload.Payload))
var columns = listOfString(namesOf(payload.Payload))
---
"insert into " ++  payload.table ++ " (" ++ columns ++ ") VALUES (" ++ values ++");"
```

Output:

```
insert into std ("studentName","course") VALUES ("Ronaldo","GOAT");
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, but can you explain me below code,
fun listOfString(a)=a map ("\""++$++"\"") joinBy ","

where did this 'a' came from?

Comment: Note that I defined a function `fun listOfString(a)` where `a` is the only parameter. In the body of the function I just used that parameter, which is the only input of the function. For clarity I just updated the answer with more details.

Comment: Is this code safe from SQL injection?

Comment: Not at all. Whenever you concatenate strings to create an SQL request you are exposing it to SQL injection. Avoid dynamic queries if you want to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

You are already using the reduce function, but you need to add double quotes around each value. Here's a modified version of your code:

In this script, the pluck function is used to iterate over the values of payload.Payload and add double quotes around each value. Then, the reduce function is used to concatenate the values with commas. This should produce the desired output with values enclosed in double quotes.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var table = "insert into " ++ payload.table

var values = payload.Payload pluck ((value, key) -> "\"" ++ value ++ "\"") reduce ((item, accumulator) -> item ++ "," ++ accumulator)

var keys = keysOf(payload.Payload) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> item ++ "," ++ accumulator)

---
table ++ keys ++ " VALUES (" ++ values ++ ");"
```